# Losing records during transitioning to a failover cluster

Tags: sql-server, high-availability, failover

Recently we had an outage in our primary SQL Server cluster and traffic was directed to the fail-over cluster. This process has taken a few seconds. The funny thing is that application logs show we have successfully inserted a few records to the database during the transition time but they do not exist in the DB!

Since the database maintenance is done by a third-party company, I do not have much detail information.

Is that event possible to have the records inserted to the DB and then lost them during the transition to the fail-over cluster?

Comment: Was the transaction explicit ? So how many records were being inserted, and not even single record inserted ?

Comment: @Shanky well, from the application's point of view, we have inserted the data to the db and returned success response to the client. That means the app has not discovered any errors or exceptions. But later on we discovered there is no records in the db. About 10 records have een affected.

Comment: Do you use distributed transactions?

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik No, Insertions are atomic operations.

Comment: Most of the time when I am asked to investigate this, I end up finding that the logging for the application is written as the application executes the code and **not** when the transaction has been committed on SQL Server which leads to a logical design flaw in the application code. Chances are high that this is the issue and I would ask a dev to look into it for the app. Unless, of course, we're talking about AGs and forced failover - then it's entirely possible. If it's an FCI, though, uncommitted transactions will be rolled back per database recovery.

Comment: Yeah, with all due respect to your developers (I'm one too), this sounds like a bug in the application.